# Заглавная или строчная?

Tags: орфография

Крутая дамочка, или **Нежнее**, чем польская панна

После "или" в таких случаях следующее слово начинается с заглавной или со строчной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если наименование литературного произведения состоит из двух названий, соединяемых союзом или, то с прописной буквы пишется также первое слово второго названия, например:опера «Леонора, или Супружеская любовь», комедия «Двенадцатая ночь, или Как вам угодно».

http://rosental.virtbox.ru/ortho_iii.html